# Error while using kable with booktabs=TRUE option in R-Studio

Tags: r, pdflatex, kable

Does anyone have problem with compiling .pdf output using kable with booktabs=TRUE option in R Studio? Without booktabs it works just fine. When I try to improve the table format adding booktabs=TRUE to kable, I get an error "! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)." followed by message of pandoc "Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43".

My code is:

```
kable(table, col.names = c("Groups", "N","% Cum", "%", "N","% Cum.", "%"),
      caption="Some Caption",row.names = FALSE,align="c",
      format ="latex", booktabs=FALSE)  %>%
      add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 3, "Group 2" = 3)) %>%
      kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a call to the `booktabs` package in LATEX.
Add this to your preamble

```
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
---
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it. The call to the booktabs and other packages used by kable was of course added to the preamble. Though it’s a funny story: after I came back from vacation and ran the code it magically worked! I don’t know what happened there. Hm… Nevertheless thanks for help very much.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (error 43). In my case, it was because at least one of my rows began with a bracket `[`. Once I removed this it compiled the pdf as usual.